# Where's the error in this for?

Tags: actionscript-3

Probably it's because I've written It, but, where's the error?

```
function getTotalVideoFrame ():int {
    if (video.current > 0) {
        var frames:int = 0;
        for (i:int = 0; i < video.current; i ++) {
            frames += video.chapters[i].frames;
        }
        frames = frames + getCurrentVideoFrame ();
        return frames;
    }
    return getCurrentVideoFrame ();
}
```

the error:

```
Scene 1, Layer 'as3', Frame 1, Line 1051    1084: Syntax error: expecting in before colon.
Scene 1, Layer 'as3', Frame 1, Line 1051    1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before rightparen.
```

if I `comment the for statement` everything go right, I must be spent to be unable to see the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing `var` in your `for` loop:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < video.current; i ++)
```

Answer (score 0):

arghh!! found it...

```
// the wrong for
for (i:int = 0; i < video.current; i ++) {
    frames += video.chapters[i].frames;
}
```

I've forgot to add the `var` keyword

```
// the right for
for (var i:int = 0; i < video.current; i ++) {
    frames += video.chapters[i].frames;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

function getTotalVideoFrame ():int {
    if (video.current > 0) {
        var frames:int = 0;
        **for (var i:int = 0; i < video.current; i++) {**
            frames += video.chapters[i].frames;
        }
        frames = frames + getCurrentVideoFrame ();
        return frames;
    }
    return getCurrentVideoFrame ();
}